# what are the steps to be taken for single-writer per partition in Apache Kafka to achieve exactly-once messaging semantics?

Tags: apache-kafka

what are the steps to be taken for single-writer per partition in Apache Kafka to achieve exactly-once messaging semantics?

How can we setup or configure or program to achieve exactly-once messaging semantics?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka itself only guarantees at-least-once semantics. Building exactly once on top is difficult. One current proposal is an idempotent producer: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Idempotent+Producer

Thus, there is no configuration yet to do exactly-once.

If you want to build something by yourself on top of Kafka for exactly-once writes, you would need something like a unique message-id and on recovery, you need to read all messages written to the topic before the crash to figure out the last successfully written message to resume producing correctly.

However, this is still no end-to-end exactly-once, but only a producer exactly-once. Not sure if this would be sufficient for your use case.